# Ajuda com método DaysOfWeek em Asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou um criando uma api utilizando Asp.Net que realiza listagens de tarefas e essas tarefas são exibidas por dia, semana, mês e ano, minha duvida é em como realizar essa chamada somente pela semana atual que estou, não estou conseguindo fazer dessa maneira abaixo, gostaria de ajuda.

```
    [HttpGet("filter/week/{macAddress}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Week(string macAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _repo.GetTodosItens(macAddress);

            var week = result.AsQueryable<TaskModel>().Where(t => t.When.DayOfWeek == DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);

            return Ok(week);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Erro: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que é retornado ao fazer desta forma? ( O que esperava/ O que recebe)

Comment: Se vai fazer o `DayOfWeek` nos dois lados, pode usar somente o `Day`. Provavelmente está tendo problemas na hora de converter isso pra SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Estava fazendo errado, com ajuda de um colega de trabalho, ele me passou o seguinte método:

```
    private static int GetWeekNumber(DateTime date)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo currentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        System.Globalization.Calendar currentCalendar = currentCulture.Calendar;

        return
            currentCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(date,
                                          currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                                          currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);

    }
```

Com ele é possivel passar a data e ele retorna a semana que estou, com isso consigo comparar com a semana atual